# QDate - Searching between two dates

Tags: c++, qt, date, search, datetime

I'm looking to preform a date search with QT's QDate type. I currently have a QDate with a specified time, and two QDate's to provide a range to search in. If the item is within the range it should return true.

```
QDate item = Apr 22nd 2013

QDate startSearch = Apr 1st 2013

QDate endSearch = Apr 30th 2013
```

I'm not aware of a built in function that does this, suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
bool withinRange = (item >= startSearch && item <= endSearch);
```

Comment: brilliant, I'm going to try it out